# Is it possible to display a VolatileImage in a JavaFX scene?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working with a `VolatileImage` to utilize hardware acceleration and was wondering if its possible to display the image in a `JavaFX` scene. I have used `SwingFXUtils.toFXImage()` for a `BufferedImage` in the past but this does not seem to support `VolatileImage`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `VolatileImage` in `JavaFX` to utilize hardware acceleration. You can use `ImageView` instead. Here's an extract from `JavaFX` architecture:

> Two graphics accelerated pipelines are implemented on the JavaFX platform:
>
> Prism processes render jobs. It can run on both hardware and software renderers, including 3-D. It is responsible for rasterization
>   and rendering of JavaFX scenes. The following multiple render paths
>   are possible based on the device being used:
>
> - DirectX 9 on Windows XP and Windows Vista
> - DirectX 11 on Windows 7
> - OpenGL on Mac, Linux, Embedded
> - Software rendering when hardware acceleration is not possible
>
> The fully hardware accelerated path is used when possible, but when it is not available, the software render path is used because the
>   software render path is already distributed in all of the Java Runtime
>   Environments (JREs). This is particularly important when handling 3-D
>   scenes. However, performance is better when the hardware render paths
>   are used.
>
> Quantum Toolkit ties Prism and Glass Windowing Toolkit together and makes them available to the JavaFX layer above them in the stack.
>   It also manages the threading rules related to rendering versus events
>   handling.

You can find further information about hardware acceleration on `JavaFX` platform here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm and here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm